# How to get image from an Image Control Type in .net c#, I need to save this image in a file and then use it for later comparing

Tags: .net, image

Basically this is what I need to do:
There is a folder which on say modifying with a product, its appearance on desktop changes, and appears to be a same folder image with a lock on it. So now I need to verify this with automation.
So my approach was to retrieve this image with C# .net and then compare it with an expected pre-stored image file. So any help on how to retrieve this image would help a lot
Don't want to use any 3rd party tools as it would increase maintenance

Any other better approach also if possible would help.

Answer (score 0):

[Previewing Image in ASP.NET Image Control using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/430320/Previewing-Image-in-ASP-NET-Image-Control-using-Cs) help you **to get image from an Image Control Type**.

You can **save the image** in the below way.

```
Image bitmap = Image.FromFile("C:\\MyFile.bmp");
bitmap.Save("C:\\MyFile2.bmp");
```

You should be able to use the [Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save.aspx) from the [Image Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) and be just fine as shown above.  The Save Method has 5 different options or overloads.

```
  //Saves this Image  to the specified file or stream.
  img.Save(filePath);

  //Saves this image to the specified stream in the specified format.
  img.Save(Stream, ImageFormat);

  //Saves this Image to the specified file in the specified format.
  img.Save(String, ImageFormat);

  //Saves this image to the specified stream, with the specified encoder and image encoder parameters.
  img.Save(Stream, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters);

  //Saves this Image to the specified file, with the specified encoder and image-encoder parameters.
  img.Save(String, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters);
```

Comment: Actually I need to get the image from image control type, in test automation using .net and c#, say if there is a image control type on desktop, i can detect it using UI automation libraries, however did not find any method to retrieve the image from that object in c#, so that's somewhere I would like to know if there is any way to achieve that.